# Vue not rendering Vuex mutation

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have a strange problem where my mutation isn't updating the view until I time travel using the debugging tool.

As you can see in the [video](https://videos2.sendvid.com/14/6d/yvabx1qg.mp4) I start typing and it changes the view on the first mutation. Then after 3 seconds have passed the second mutation happens although the view doesn't reflect that. When I then click time travel to the previous mutation and back it start's working as normal.

Any one have an idea why this is happening?

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Comment: The reason I haven't is because there is a lot of code.

Comment: But you seem to have a clue how it SHOULD work and you TRIED something, so we are able to find the bugs in YOUR code not to guess your mistakes.

Comment: @jdickel have added snips to the answer below if you'd like to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is really hard to know the cause without seeing the code, I'll take a guess.

This may be due to the way you are updating your state in the mutation.

Vue cannot set watchers to object properties, so when you do something like this `state.user.isTyping = true`, it won't trigger an update. If you have something like that in your mutation, try using `Vue.$set(state.user, 'isTyping', true)`

you can also trick it using `forceUpdate()` but that's a naughty hack you should try to avoid.

Comment: The way I'm updating is like this: `this.$store.dispatch('messages/sendTyping', data);`

Comment: but how are you handling the change inside the mutation?

Comment: Like this (sorry I can't seem to format it):
   [types.MESSAGE_RECIVED_TYPING_SUCCESS] (state, payload) {
    state.messages
      .find(message => message.id == payload.id)
      .typing, payload.typing;
  },

Comment: If I use Vue.$set() it doesn't do anything. `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_Vue__.a.$set is not a function`

Comment: Looks like that may have been your issue. Try something like this (haven't tested it) 'Vue.$set(state.messages.find(message => message.id == payload.id), 'typing', payload.typing);' Make sure you import Vue

Comment: Import vue in store using `import Vue from 'vue';`

Comment: Do you recommend using Vue.$set() on all mutations? Well setters I mean. Also I already have it imported so that can't be the problem.

Comment: Ok I think this is the problem `Duplicate keys detected: '0'. This may cause an update error.` not sure how that is.

Comment: Use of vue depends on the type of variable. The reactivity is a bit of a stumbling block for people starting vue. I recommend reading over https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: I'm not actually new, this just seems to be a strange bug.

Comment: the duplicate keys error is something I'd expect from the rendering in v-for, and not related to the models not updating

Comment: I have a bit of reactivity using the same method: [video](https://videos2.sendvid.com/4e/1b/1gvs52vn.mp4).

Comment: @JamieBonnett why not share your codes? then we can help you from there, it will save our time to guess what happened.

Comment: @Sphinx There is a lot of code, basically I'm using an even to pass the person list (selected to the chat component) and pass them into a prop e.g. like so `<chat-preview-list class="pane" :recipient.sync="recipient" :messages.sync="messages" />`
`<chat-message-view class="pane" :style="{flexGrow: 1}" :recipient.sync="recipient" />`

Comment: @JamieBonnett how you can action=sendTyping at your view? you will bind the input event like `@input="typingHandler()"`, please share the codes for `typingHandler`

Comment: @Sphinx there is no action in the component as it sent over a socket, and recipient is passed in as a synced prop (so that it changes with the vuex store) so I just have this `<span v-if="recipient.typing">is typing...</span>`.

Comment: @JamieBonnett your use case will be if A is typing, it will trigger sendTyping, then both A and B(receipient) will receive the typing by `socket.on('reciveTyping')`, right? If so, how you trigger sendTyping? you must bind the event for the input, if not, how you know A is typing?

Comment: @Sphinx Ohh I get you sorry, ok I do this (excuse the formatting, I don't know why stackoverflow does this): `typing: function () { let data = { id: this.recipient.id, typing: true }; if (!this.recipient.typing) { this.$store.dispatch('messages/sendTyping', data); } clearTimeout(this.typing_timer); this.typing_timer = setTimeout(function () { data.typing = false; this.$store.dispatch('messages/sendTyping', data); }.bind(this), 3000); }` Binded like so: `v-on:keydown="typing()"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170398/discussion-between-sphinx-and-jamie-bonnett).

Comment: wow, quite the discussion you had there. Hope you got it resolved. I did want to mention though, that sometimes the issue with reactivity has to do with when an item is defined. If a variable is not in data during instantiation, vue does not create getters and setters, which is why you may be seeing them for some vars, but not for others.